# Extend global config, jshint

Tags: javascript, jshint

Is there a way to extend global jshint config with local, and not fully override it? *My global config is in User folder*.

Like

```
{
    "extends": "~/.jshintrc",
    "node": true
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to used the tilde but couldn't find a good way of doing this, the best solution is to use your home path explicitly

```
{
   "extends": "Users/<user-name>/.jshintrc"
}
```

Hope it helps